# Multitouch gestures in paperjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

Creating and manipulating complicated shapes flexibly using mouse events is possible in paperjs. The project I am working on looks good on desktops/laptops. However, I want to get shape manipulation work with touch events like pinch and zoom also. Is multitouch interface possible in paperjs or do I have to add another library for touch support.

Answer (score 2):

you can make an event listener for various touch events:

`ontouchstart` `ontouchmove` `ontouchend` `ongesturestart` `ongesturechange` `ongestureend`

from there you can track the touch postions from the event object

`var touch = event.touches[0];`

```
touchX = touch.pageX;
touchY = touch.pageY;
```

you can easily reposition objects based on those points.

Scaling and rotating based on gestures is a little more complicated, but also doable using the gesture events...

have a look at the link below, it is simple plain javascript and it is not as complicated as you might think

http://techblog.floorplanner.com/post/20528546052/interactive-svg-on-the-ipad

Comment: that can be definitely done. I was looking for the paperjs way if at all paperjs offers some.

Comment: the api is fairly limited for actual interaction api's and is more geared toward actual drawing and utilities for working with canvas. There is the [tool object](http://paperjs.org/reference/tool) that has a few things for handling some mouse events, but nothing for touch, (certainly not multi) as of right now. I guess you  could maybe extend upon those API's but that is a whole other task in itself